# Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующему требуемому параметру. Как исправить?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Мне нужно осуществить переход на другую страницу, но появляется ошибка

> CS7036: Отсутствует аргумент, соответствующему требуемому параметру "student" из "PageStudent_Menu.PageStudent_Menu(Students)

```cs
public PageStudent_Menu_Test()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void BackMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new PageStudent_Menu());
}
```

Но в той другой странице задействован класс, и я не знаю как осуществить в таком случае переход

```cs
public PageStudent_Menu(Students student)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ComboTEST.ItemsSource = ХолчукУПТеорияВероятностейEntities1.GetContext().TitleQuestion.ToList();
    NameStudents.ID_Student = student.ID_Student;           
    studentname.Text = student.Surname;
}
```

Сам класс называется `NameStudents`:

```cs
internal class NameStudents
{
    public static int ID_Student { get; set; }
}
```

Он нужен, чтобы при авторизации студента высвечивалось имя этого самого студента.
Но вопрос остается таким же, что вписать, чтобы осуществить переход?

Comment: Внимание на `public PageStudent_Menu(Students student)`, а затем на `new PageStudent_Menu()`. Вы для создания класса требуете `Students`, но при создании, игнорируете это требование, пытаясь сделать класс без `Students`. Вы уж определитесь, нужен он или нет. Если да, то смотрите, где в вашем проекте этот `Students` есть и передавайте его `new PageStudent_Menu(сюда)`.

Comment: Так в этом и проблема, что я не понимаю, что передавать в new PageStudent_Menu(сюда), что именно

Comment: Если вписать new PageStudent_Menu(Students student) то выйдет ошибка "имя student" не существует в данном контексте", потому что Students - таблица в бд с ФИО и данными для авторизации, а student - параметр. NameStudents класс, который определяет ID студента, а параметр показывает имя того, кто входит в приложение. И вопрос остается актуальным, ЧТО ВПИСАТЬ В NavigationService.Navigate(new PageStudent_Menu(СЮДА)); Подскажите, или направьте куда смотреть

Comment: Вы серьезно? Вы сами требуете объект `Students`, а потом пишете "не знаю что передавать и от куда взять"? Простите, а нам от куда знать что у вас там в коде, где этот `Students` находится, и так далее? Вот ответьте на вопрос: Хочу окна помыть, да вот средство для мытья окон требуется, не знаю где оно у меня в квартире, подскажете? Думаю нет, ибо вы не знаете вообще ничего про меня и мою квартиру. Также и код, я не знаю где у вас там и что. Вы сами требуете объект типа `Students` для создания класса, вот его и передавайте, хоть `new(new Students())`, хоть `var students = ...; new (students)`.

Comment: Так я новичок в этой теме и пытаюсь разобраться хоть в чем-то. Вы мне кажитесь грубым, а если надо что-то показать, чтобы исправить проблему, то могу редактировать сам вопрос и добавить необходимый материал.  Я попробовал new(new Students()), но теперь не отображается имя вошедшего студента

Comment: @makswarden Найдите у себя в коде, откуда у вас ещё вызывается метод `PageStudent_Menu` и где в том месте кода берут `Students`, чтобы передать его в этот метод.

Comment: Кажусь грубым, кидайте тревогу, пусть модераторы наказывают. Я лишь пытаюсь донести до вас то, что вы просите от нас, по сути невозможное. Как вот со средством для мытья окон, вы ведь не сможете дать ответ на этот вопрос, верно? Вот также и мы, сообщество SO не сможем дать ответ на "где в вашем коде объект Students", ибо он может быть где угодно, и нам остается лишь гадать, играть в вангу, чего неприемлемо на данном ресурсе, ибо не забывайте, SO это не форум, где мы общаемся, а база вопросов и ответов на них, где каждый вопрос должен быть полезен не только вам (автору), но и будущему читателю